# Will it be OK with sleeping mat being as wide as tent 52" both

Tags: sleeping

I am looking at the Exped Duo sleeping mat as 52 inches wide and it being just as wide as the tent Nemo Aurora 2p. It this likely to cause any strange problems?

Comment: You may find this question and my answer interesting: [Sleeping pad slightly wider than tent?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/25835/sleeping-pad-slightly-wider-than-tent/)

Answer (score 6):

You may have problems getting it in and spread properly.
You may find it is just that bit wider it forces the edges of the tent out.

And you may have to put anything you bring into the tent onto the mat, depending on the length of it.

In the past I have used a matras style airbed that fitted snugly in the inner tent I used back then but the tent had a good fly sheet that was enough wider that it did not become a problem. I have been in a tent where any stress on the inner tent would have resulted in leaks through touching layers. In such a tent I would not use a snugly fitting mat or airbed.

Comment: "I have been in a tent where any stress on the inner tent would have resulted in leaks through touching layers." +1. I have used many tents that worked like this, any stretching at all was a risk. I would recommend against trying it.